# Not able to play media file after navigation on C#/XAML metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, media

Here I am pasting the code. My app has capability to access music library. I am not getting any exception but media file is not being played after navigation. [Here](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=9E70869A1583FA52&id=9E70869A1583FA52!273) is the project hosted on skydrive

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Click Me" Margin="563,357,0,373" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync("video.mp4");
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MediaPlayback), file);
}
```

MediaPlayback.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <MediaElement  x:Name="MyMediaPlayback" Height="350" Width="640"/>
</Grid>
```

MediaPlayback.xaml.cs

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file = e.Parameter as StorageFile;

    try
    {
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        MyMediaPlayback.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        MyMediaPlayback.Play();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common problem with OnNavigatedTo is that it gets called before Loaded event fires, which is when the control actually gets added to the visual tree. I am only guessing, but you might need to wait for the page to load before calling .Play(). Also I think by default MediaElement is set up to play automatically when you set the source, so calling Play might be unnecessary or in fact it could be what breaks here. MediaElement still has many basic bugs in Windows 8 RTM and needs to be used carefully to work around them. This would also be an excellent use case for a call to "await [WaitForLoadedAsync](http://jupitertoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/18608#346231)()" to see if waiting for that event is necessary instead of hunting for the navigation parameter in the Loaded event handler.